# In what episode of TNG was an ancient Vulcan psionic weapon discovered?

Tags: story-identification, star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification

In what episode of TNG was an ancient Vulcan psionic weapon discovered? If I recall correctly, the device had 3 parts: life, death and balance in between. It worked only against aggression (to the best of my recollection).

Comment: The three parts (glyphs) were War, Death, and it was Peace that stood between them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The episode that featured the device was called [Gambit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambit_%28Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation%29):

The artifacts are part of an ancient Vulcan telepathic weapon, the
[Stone of Gol](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Stone_of_Gol). Picard realizes the true nature of it, once a powerful weapon but utterly useless against people who don't bear aggressive thoughts.

> **PICARD:** *Listen to me, all of you! Drop your weapons! Do it! Don't make any aggressive movements. The resonator amplifies violent
>   feelings and emotions. And that's why you wanted me to pick up the
>   phaser. That's how you were able to kill Narik and Vekor. But I can
>   see the symbol on that third artefact, and **it is the Vulcan symbol for
>   peace standing between the symbols for war and death.** It's a warning
>   that the power of the resonator can be overcome by peace.*

Comment: Thnk you, I needed that to answer the question did Volcans lie question. IIRC in that epsiode a Volkan indeed did not tell the truth from point of view of others.